# How to find hour in getdate() is expired

Tags: sql, asp.net, datetime, c#-3.0

In my DB I have stored time as datetime . On my asp.net page I want to retrieve it and find out if the retrieved time is expired or not. Expiry time is 8hours.  What is the best method for this?

I have tried out like this . But didn't get  proper solution

```
DateTime DB_time = Convert.ToDateTime(dr_pass[2].ToString()); //time from database

if (DB_time > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-8)) //password is too old 
{                
    return false ;
}
else
{ 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is DBD_time? Please show its declaration and its initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime DB_time = Convert.ToDateTime(dr_pass[2].ToString()); //time from database

if (DateTime.Now < DB_time.AddHours(8)) 
{                
    return true; // password valid
}
else
{ 
    return false; // password expired
}
```